# asp.net core 2.0 DI Injecting multiple classes of IInterface into a controller

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm going to create hundreds of classes. If they all implemented the same class, do I have to register them one by one?

Example

```
public class Service<TEntity>: IService<TEntity> {...}

public Interface IService<TEntity> where TEntity : class {...}

public class class1 : Service<apple>, IClass1 {...}

public class class234 : Service<orange>, IClass234 {...}
```

In my controller I would like to inject it like this

```
public class FoodController : Controller{
     private IClass1 _class1;
     private IClass234 _class234;

     FoodController(IClass1 ic1, IClass234 ic234){
          _class1 = ic1;
          _class234 = ic234;
     }
}
```

I've done this before with Unity in older versions of `ASP.NET` How can I do this with the built in DI of `ASP.NET CORE 2.0`?

In the controller, I can inject the specific interface of `IClass1` and `IClass234` in the constructor. This is what I'm trying to achieve because I would also like to use the other methods from the other interfaces that the classes implement.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Is there a way to register all 234 classes without typing out services.addTransient...
}
```

Comment: https://medium.com/agilix/asp-net-core-inject-all-instances-of-a-service-interface-64b37b43fdc8

Comment: @JohanP I've already gone through that. That's not what I'm looking for. I want to inject each service separately in the controller because they will also have class specific functionality.

Comment: If you have multiple implementations of the same interface, then it will inject an `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: @JohanP  I would have to iterate through IEnumerable or select the instance I want with linq. How is that related to what I'm asking for?

Comment: Is your question not `// Is there a way to register all 234 classes without typing out services.addTransient...`? If it is, then the link I provided and you have already seen answers your question. If your question is what your title is, then I have already answered it above, it will inject an `IEnumerable<T>` then you will have to use linq to find it. If that is not your question, maybe make it clearer.

Comment: @JohanP Ok, sorry for the confusion I'll rephrase my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the standard DI container you do have to register one by one.

But you can use another library to register it automatically by naming convention:

https://www.google.com/amp/s/andrewlock.net/using-scrutor-to-automatically-register-your-services-with-the-asp-net-core-di-container/amp/